# multiple files input to stanford NER preserving naming for each output

Tags: java, bash, stanford-nlp

I have many files, (the NYTimes corpus for '05, '06, & '07) , I want to run them all through the [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), "easy" you might think, "just follow the commands in the README doc", but if you thought that just now, you would be mistaken, because my situation is a bit more complicated. I don't want them all outputted into some big jumbled mess, I want to preserve the naming structure of each file, so for example, one file is named `1822873.xml` and I processed it earlier using the following command:

```
java -mx600m -cp /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/stanford-ner-3.5.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/1822873.xml -outputFormat inlineXML >> output.curtis
```

If I were to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544545/python-or-bash-script-to-pass-all-files-in-a-folder-to-java-command-line), i.e. many files all listed in the command one after the other, and then pipe that to somewhere, wouldn't it just send them all to the same file? That sounds like a headache disastor of the highest order.

Is there some way to send each file to a seperate output file, so for instance, our old friend `1822873.xml` would emerge from this process as, say `1822873.output.xml`, and likewise for each of the other thousand some odd files. Please keep in mind that I'm trying to achieve this [expeditiously](http://listenonrepeat.com/watch/?hl=en-GB&gl=SG&v=6Z66wVo7uNw?v=6Z66wVo7uNw#Curtis_Mayfield_-_Move_On_Up).

I guess this should be possible, but what is the best way to do it? with some kind of terminal command, or maybe write a small script?

Maybe one among you has some experience with this type of thing.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

you can do it with a bash script [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588423/bash-script-to-navigate-directory-substructure-and-then-operate-on-xml-files).

---

@duhaime I tried that but I had an issue with the classifier, also is it possible to formulate the output for that as inline xml?

With respect to my original question, [check out what I've found](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-August/003929.html):

> > > > > > Unfortunately, there is no option to have multiple input files go to
> > > > > >             multiple output files.  The best you can do in the current situation
> > > > > >             is to run the CRFClassifier once for each input file you have.  If
> > > > > >             you
> > > > > >             have a ton of small files, loading the model will be an expensive
> > > > > >             part
> > > > > >             of this operation, and you might want to use the CRFClassifier
> > > > > >             server
> > > > > >             program and feed files one at a time through the client.  However, I
> > > > > >             doubt that will be worth the effort except in the specific case of
> > > > > >             having very many small files.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > We will try to add this as a feature for the next distribution (we
> > > > > >             have a general fix-it day coming up) but no promises.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > John

My files are all numbered in ascending order, do you think it would be possible to write some kind of bash script with a loop to processes each of them one at a time?

Comment: I've done this for Python; could you run a Python script instead? Which classifier do you want to load?

Comment: @duhaime I ended up doing it with a bash script like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588423/bash-script-to-navigate-directory-substructure-and-then-operate-on-xml-files)

Comment: I'm glad you got there!

Comment: :) thanks. and know that I do appreciate your consideration of my original question, it's always good to look at/ think about things, from many angles.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-filelist` option and the `-outputDirectory` option, you can read in a list of files you wish to process, and the directory in which you would like to save the processed files. Example:

```
java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -prop annotators.prop -filelist list_of_files_to_process.txt -outputDirectory "my_output_directory"
```

For reference, here are the contents of `list_of_files_to_process.txt`:

```
C:/Users/dduhaime/Desktop/pq/analysis/data/washington_correspondence_data/collect_full_text/washington_full_text\02-09-02-0334.txt
C:/Users/dduhaime/Desktop/pq/analysis/data/washington_correspondence_data/collect_full_text/washington_full_text\02-09-02-0335.txt
C:/Users/dduhaime/Desktop/pq/analysis/data/washington_correspondence_data/collect_full_text/washington_full_text\02-09-02-0336.txt
C:/Users/dduhaime/Desktop/pq/analysis/data/washington_correspondence_data/collect_full_text/washington_full_text\02-09-02-0337.txt
```

Here are the contents of my `annotators.prop` file:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, gender, sentiment, natlog, entitymentions, relation
```

And here's what the contents of `my_output_directory` will look like:
[image]