# bash script to navigate directory substructure and then operate on .xml files

Tags: linux, bash, io, directory-structure

I tired this:

```
for dir in /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NYTimesCorpus/2007/02/*/
    for f in *.xml ; do
        echo $f | grep -q '_output\.xml$' && continue # skip output files
        g="$(basename $f .xml)_output.xml"
        java -mx600m -cp /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/stanford-ner-3.5.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile $f -outputFormat inlineXML > $g
    done
done
```

which is based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux), but that didn't work.

I have a folder stucture such that within the directory `NYTimesCorpus` there is a directory `2007` and within that a directory `01` and also `02`, `03`, and so on...

then within `01` there is again `01`,`02`,`03`,...

in each of these terminal directories there are many .xml files to which I want to apply the script:

```
for f in *.xml ; do
    echo $f | grep -q '_output\.xml$' && continue # skip output files
    g="$(basename $f .xml)_output.xml"
    java -mx600m -cp /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/stanford-ner-3.5.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile $f -outputFormat inlineXML > $g
done
```

but there are so many different directories that running it within each dirctory is a form of rare torture. apart from `2007` I also have `2006` and `2005`, so ideally what I would like to do is run it once and have the program just navigate that structure on its own.

My attempts this far have not been successful, perhaps one among you would know how to achieve this?

Thank you for your consideration.

### **UPDATE**

```
textFile=./scrypt.sh
outputFormat=inlineXML
Loading classifier from /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.2 sec].
CRFClassifier tagged 71 words in 5 documents at 959.46 words per second.
CRFClassifier invoked on Sun Apr 12 19:33:34 HKT 2015 with arguments:
   -loadClassifier /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile ./scrypt.sh -outputFormat inlineXML
    loadClassifier=/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is a good solution. It sounds like all the xml files are at the same directory depth, so try this:

```
dir=/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus
for f in $dir/NYTimesCorpus/*/*/*/*.xml; do
    [[ $f == *_output.xml ]] && continue # skip output files
    g="${f%.xml}_output.xml"
    java -mx600m \
         -cp $dir/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/stanford-ner-3.5.1.jar \
         edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier \
         -loadClassifier $dir/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz \
         -textFile "$f" \
         -outputFormat inlineXML > "$g"
done
```

The glob pattern `$dir/NYTimesCorpus/*/*/*/*.xml` specifies that the wanted xml files are exactly 3 levels below NYTimesCorpus. That that is the wrong depth, then alter the number of `*/` in the pattern.

If the xml files can appear at varying depths, use `find`, or in bash use:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in $dir/NYTimesCorpus/**/*.xml; do
```

[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Comment: ok, first let me say: bravo. absolutely top-ranked. fantastic. hats off to you sir for this phenominal solution. and then follow that up by, what is the mechanism by which this works where the others did not? how could this be changes to accomodate a slightly different depth?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `find` since it works recursively:

```
find /path/to/xmls -type f ! -name '*_output.xml' -name '*.xml' -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```

For better readability I would save the actions that should be executed on each file to `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

f="$1"
g="${f%%.*}_output.xml"
java -mx600m -cp /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/stanford-ner-3.5.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier /home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/NER/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile "$f" -outputFormat inlineXML > "$g"
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Comment: so in /path/to/xmls do I have to specify each directory?

Comment: so `/path/to/xmls` can just be the, relative, root directory, i.e. `/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/nytimes_corpus/` is that it?

Comment: Yes, in your example this should be the correct path

Comment: i just tried it but it didn't work. i got the error `Exception in thread main edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: *.xml (No such file or directory)
`

Comment: What is the output of `find /path/to/xmls -type f -name '*.xml'` ?

Comment: i did `find . -type f -name '*.xml'` which was also how I ran the original command you recommended, with a `.` and that one I just did, that you recommended here in the comments, it displayed all the .xml files correctly, in `./29/1645744.xml
` that way for all files

Comment: The script by @hek2mgl needs an edit. Replace the assignment to `g` by: `g="$(dirname $f)/$(basename $f .xml)_output.xml"`

Comment: it seems not to have worked, the program terminated and there were no output files in the respective folders, maybe i have to specify the `dirname` for the correct number of directories until the `.xml` files?

Comment: It should be `g="${f%%.*}_output.xml"`. Edited that

Comment: I think it's not working, since I don't see the output files anywhere, I posted what is being written to the console under the **UPDATE** section of my original question, it's also writing an empty file called `_output.xml` to where ever I call it from

Comment: @hek2mgl no! that's not what's happening at all! what's happening is a file called `_output.xml` seems to be being written after it reads an entire directory and then it goes and reads a new directory, erases that file and starts over.

Comment: The command above won't do that. Are you using the command *exactly* as I posted it?

Comment: I did exactly as you had posted. it seems that it was doing that, such as there was a file called `_output.xml` and the time stamp on it kept changing and getting more recent, it would have a big size and then the size would be zero

Comment: It should be `f=$1` .. Changed that. Please try it again

Comment: i tried also that and the behaviour is still as I have described before

Comment: i accepted the other answer becasue it seems to work but I want to tell you that I am very grateful for your help and even it's clear that glennjackman cited your answer as using `find` as a good solution so anyway I upvoted your answer and i appreciate your efforts. thank you.

Comment: Thanks and you are welcome. I'm just wondering why it doesn't work. It should! I've even created a test setup and everything was working fine. Sure I cannot emulate that java process, I just did `cp "$f" "g"` and it worked as expected. The java process shouldn't be the problem.. I cannot look at your terminal, but I would debug it step by step. Is `$f` ok? Is `$g` ok? Is every file listed properly? .. Then you should get it working